# Holomorphism check for the functions $F(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(t-z)^2}dt$ and $G(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{|t-z|^2}dt$

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, holomorphic-functions

Which one is holomorphic and why, out of:
$$F(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(t-z)^2}dt$$
and
$$G(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{|t-z|^2}dt$$
I tried using residues (calculating the integral and checking the holomorphism property), but have not succeeded. Need another way.Perhaps without calculating the integrals.

Comment: the answer is $F(z)$

Comment: I wonder if any of them even converges...

Comment: @tired How do you know?

Comment: $G(z)$ is real valued so if it were holomorphic, since its imaginary part is $0$ (i.e. constant), $G(z)$ must be constant, which doesn't seem to be the case.